# Is there going to be a really bad Solar Storm in 2014?

Tags: solar-storm

Here are some [Articles](http://www.google.com.au/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Solar%20storm%202014&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=ctrl&ei=N1PzUqHkDayN8Qev1ID4Cw&gws_rd=cr) I've found.

Is it true? If it is, How big could it be?, what might be possible or will be possible?, what will happen?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it true?

Solar storms are like Earth storms: unpredictable until they are quite near.

> What will happen?

If there is a massive solar storm, we will experience power outages in long lines (e.g. U.S.A. mainland, Russia), communications disruption on satellite links (and again in long copper lines), and very nice auroras.

Comment: finally I'll be able to show my wife that aurorae are real :-)